# Azure WCF has https wsdl url but endpoint url is in http

Tags: c#, azure, wcf-binding, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to access Azure WCF in SPD. The http wsdl and endpoint works as expected, but the https wsdl cannot handle a https endpoint. I opened up the wsdl and can see only a http endpoint.

Can anyone tell me how to have a https endpoint in wsdl soap:address location?

using the https wsdl and http endpoint in SPD for ECT I can connect to the WCF service but it doesn't generate a tree view!

At the end it generates an error: "**The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExptionDetailsFaults... blah blah blah**" which I'm pretty sure that the config file has serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" behavior already

config

```
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
            <defaultPorts>
              <add scheme="http" port="80" />
              <add scheme="https" port="443" />
            </defaultPorts>
          </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

csdef

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="SPO_LOB" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2012-10.1.8">
  <WebRole name="SPO_LOB" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
          <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="certsvc" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
          storeName="CA" />
    </Certificates>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="democloudsvc1" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
    </Imports>
    <LocalResources>
      <LocalStorage name="SPO_LOB.svclog" sizeInMB="1000" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
    </LocalResources>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Comment: Please post the web.config and the ServiceDefinition.csdef of your WCF service

Comment: I'm using a self-signed certificate, could this be a problem?

Comment: stop using wsdl period.  Use and expose  REST endpoint.  Make your life easier, stop being monolithic.

Comment: Hello @kmanxi: Have you figured out the solution. I have the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

How is your mex endpoint defined in services section of web.config. it should be like this,

Please note the binding has to be "mexHttpsBinding" -  (https)

Comment: added these lines in config: 

`<service name="Service1" behaviorConfiguration="SVCbehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:443"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureBasic" name="basicHttpSecure" contract="Service1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>`



I will post results if this works out or not

Answer (score 0):

added mex binding and endpoint now is in https

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureBasic" proxyAddress="http://localhost:80">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="SPO_LOB.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="SVCbehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:443"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureBasic" name="basicHttpSecure" contract="SPO_LOB.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
```

The remaining problem now is when I connect SPO BCS to the service it generates the error I mentioned above. Even though IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults is set to true in config